# How to return mutated values from a custom React hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to pass my component state to a custom hook and return true if my state changes as compared to initial state.

---

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useDirtyState = (props:any) => {
//Possibly use local state and set it to true and return that

  const isFirstRender = useRef<boolean>(true)
  const isDirty = useRef<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false
      return
    }
    isDirty.current = true
    console.log(isDirty.current) // is true
  }, [props])
  console.log(isDirty.current) // I return this and it is false :(
} 

//In some other component 
const isDirty = useDirtyStaate(state)//Expect this to be true when state is changed
```

The problem is that the outer console.log shows false even if props change because my effect runs after that (I guess?). How do I return the correct value from this hook ?

---

**Edit**: I tried adding a local state to the hook and setting it to true and returning it. While this approach works, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way as it seems to cause 1 extra render.

Comment: Could you say a bit about your use case? The logic seems a bit light for its own hook. You are effectively answering the question of whether the state has changed via the useEffect dependency; why not just use useEffect rather than a custom hook?

Comment: I want to add some warning to warn users while they are leaving components with unsaved changes. And I thought it would be better to have this hook return 1 value rather than copy this snippet in all components. Also makes the intent clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store the original value in a ref and compare it to the value provided during render:

```js
const {useRef, useState} = React;

// You can implement the value comparison using your preferred method
function areValuesEqual (value1, value2) {
  return Object.is(value1, value2);
}

/**
 * TS:
 * function useValueChanged <T>(value: T): boolean
 */
function useValueChanged (value) {
  const originalRef = useRef(value);
  return !areValuesEqual(originalRef.current, value);
}

function Example () {
  const renderCountRef = useRef(0);
  renderCountRef.current += 1;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => setCount(n => n + 1);
  const didChange = useValueChanged(count);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Render count: {renderCountRef.current}</div>
      <div>Changed: {didChange ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Clicks: {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I know that this will work. I was wondering if there is a way to do it without that extra render. Please check my edit where I have done something similar. So does this mean that this cannot be done without using state ?

Comment: If you are trying to avoid using state, then see my updated answer.

Comment: Your answer is great, but areValuesEqual should probably be implemented in a more robust way (especially if the states are objects). For example, one could use Lodash's isEqual.